# Cypher merge nodes with same property and collected the other property

Tags: neo4j, merge, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have nodes with this structure

```
(g:Giocatore { nome, match, nazionale})

(nome:'Del Piero', match:'45343', nazionale:'ITA')
(nome:'Messi', match:'65324', nazionale:'ARG')
(nome:'Del Piero', match:'18235', nazionale:'ITA')
```

The property 'match' is unique (ID's of match) while there are several 'nome' with the same name.
I want to merge all the nodes with the same 'nome' and create a collection of different 'match' like this

```
(nome:'Del Piero', match:[45343,18235], nazionale:'ITA')
(nome:'Messi', match:'65324', nazionale:'ARG')
```

I tried with apoc library too but nothing works.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this query :

```
MATCH (n:Giocatore)
WITH n.nome AS nome, collect(n) AS node2Merge
WITH node2Merge, extract(x IN node2Merge | x.match) AS matches
  CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(node2Merge) YIELD node
  SET node.match = matches
```

Here I'm using APOC to merge the nodes, but then I do a map transformation on the node list to have an array of `match`, and I set it on the merged node.

I don't know if you have a lot of `Giocatore` nodes, so perhaps this query will do an OutOfMemory exception, so you will have to batch your query. You can for example replace the first line by `MATCH (n:Giocatore) WHERE n.nome STARTS WITH 'A'` and repeat it for each letter or you can also use the `apoc.periodic.iterate` procedure :

```
    CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
       'MATCH (n:Giocatore) WITH n.nome AS nome, collect(n) AS node2Merge RETURN node2Merge, extract(x IN node2Merge | x.match) AS matches', 
       'CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(node2Merge) YIELD node
        SET node.match = matches',
        {batchSize:1000,parallel:true,retries:3,iterateList:true}
    ) YIELD batches, total
```

Comment: i tried with the query but return an error: "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound: Node with id 1199381 has been deleted in this transaction"

Comment: I have updated my queries ( ie. calcuting the matches array before the deleteion of ndoes in the apoc procedure)